# Can ArgoCD deploy a Helm chart from Git repository, not from Helm chart repository?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, gitops

I've tried the Application definition below, but it's just not synchronizing by ArgoCD without any logging. Synchronization process just keeps hanging.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: guestbook
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  destination:
    namespace: guestbook
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
  source:
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - "values.yaml"
    repoURL: 'https://{private git server}/guestbook'
    targetRevision: HEAD
```

Git repository `https://{private git server}/guestbook` has the following file structure of a Helm chart:

```
- charts (folder)
- templates (folder)
- Chart.yaml
- values.yaml
```

Helm chart gets successfully deployed when run outside of ArgoCD with `helm install guestbook . --namespace guestbook` from the root of the cloned git repository with the chart.

Git repository and access credentials are configured in ArgoCD dashboard and ArgoCD connects to the repo successfully.

Comment: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#helm-chart-repositories. It says here, "for private repos, you may need to configure access credentials".

Comment: Also, what is your Argo setup like - on-prem or public cloud?

Comment: Git repo credentials configured in ArgoCD and ArgoCD connects to the repo successfully. ArgoCD is deployed in the public cloud.

Comment: I'm surprised someone voted for closing this question without any comment, which is quite irresponsible.

Answer (score 3):

Path should contain a Chart.yaml file.

````
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: test-apps
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: argocd
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: argocd
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
  source:
    path: argocd-example-apps
    repoURL: https://github.com/stevesea/argocd-helm-app-of-apps-example.git
    targetRevision: test
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - test-values.yaml```
````

Comment: Here is another example. https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/introduction-argocd-applicationset

Comment: Yes, I tried `path: .` in my case, with no effect. What's especially surprising, ArgoCD gives no information on the issue, it's just silently hanging when running synchronization. I've also tried two different installations of ArgoCD - one from Helm chart, another from manifest, and they both behave differently on the same Kubernetes cluster. In this shape ArgoCD is not prod ready.

Comment: They way they handle helmchart is a dirty workaround in my modest optioning, but this worked for me.